# How to integrate Programmatically layout into static layout(.xml)?

Tags: java, android

can any one help me how to add dynamic tablelayout into static main.xml layout, in the static layout i added the buttons and textview. i want add the dynamic tablelayout into specific linearlayout in the .xml form.

Comment: can you post your static layout.

Comment: This is my static layout

Comment: can u send your mail id i'll send the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically, you can create a dynamic tablelayout. Add that table layout to the layout that you have defined in XML using the `addView()` method:

**Example**

```
//get the linearlayout from xml
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
//dynamically create your table layout 
TableLayout tablelayout = new TableLayout(this);
//add tablelayout to linearlayout
linearLayout.addView(tablelayout);
```

Comment: And for the dynamic creation of the `TableLayout` you would create (for example) new TextViews using: `TextView view = new TextView(context);` and add them to the tableLayout like: `tableLayout.add(view)`. If you need new Rows, you would do the same thing but make a new [`TableRow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)

Answer (score 0):

//this is your layout in xml

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_parent);
```

//this dynamically you are creating in your activity

```
TableLayout tablelayout = new TableLayout(this);
```

//Next add the new tablelayout to your linear layout

```
  linearLayout.addView(tablelayout, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```